Switch user via ssh in same server using Jenkins pipeline
I'm unable to ssh to an ec2 server as 'ubuntu' user inside jenkins pipeline. After ssh login, the user remains as 'jenkins' instead of 'ubuntu' user.
I am getting this output against sh 'whoami && pwd'
+ whoami
jenkins
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/boighor_pipeline

pipeline code
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('SSH to EC2') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "credential-is", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
                    sh 'whoami && pwd'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Checkout Code') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'jenkins',
                   credentialsId: 'Test_Jenkins',
                   url: 'https://github.com/repository.git'
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            echo 'Pipeline execution completed.'
        }
    }
}


Expected outcome
Output of 'whoami' will be 'ubuntu' instead of 'jenkins'

SSH in Jenkins Pipeline can generally be achieved with the SSH Pipeline Steps. In your situation where you want to SSH to an AWS EC2 as the ubuntu user and execute a shell command whoami && pwd:
stage('SSH to EC2') {
  steps {
    script {
      withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'credential-is', keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
        Map remote = [user: 'ubuntu', identityFile: keyfile, name: '<ec2-server hostname>', host: '<ec2-server ip address>', allowAnyHosts: true]
        sshCommand(remote: remote, command: 'whoami && pwd')
      }
    }
  }
}

